# AngularJS : Render child li when parent li is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a requirement where i need to display only the child of the selected li.
Ex. In the image shown below, **EIS_ASCP_FORECAST_SETS_V** is checked, so it's child FND_USER and MRP_FORECAST_DESIGNATORS_V is shown and rest of the elements are hidden. Similarly, when FND_USER is selected, it's child must be shown. The tree is created using jquery and is dynamic. I'm using AngularJS for rest of the page.

[image]

I tried using `$(event.target).parent().find('li')` but was not able to get the child element out of it.

Code for forming the tree

```
<li class="treeView">
<a ng-click="getViewColumns('EIS_ASCP_FORECAST_SETS_V', '724')" href=""><b>EIS_ASCP_FORECAST_SETS_V</b></a>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true" ng-click="useInSelect('EIS_ASCP_FORECAST_SETS_V')">
    <ul>
        <li><a ng-click="getViewColumns('FND_USER', '724')" href="">FND_USER</a>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" ng-click="useInSelect('FND_USER')">
        <li><a ng-click="getViewColumns('MRP_FORECAST_DESIGNATORS_V', '724')" href="">MRP_FORECAST_DESIGNATORS_V</a>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" ng-click="useInSelect('MRP_FORECAST_DESIGNATORS_V')"></a>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Show some efforts what you have tried so far.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi i didn't understand how to start.

Comment: @Sukesh, just see about [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive

Comment: We can help you to dubug. We can not write complete code for you.

Comment: @Grundy i didn't use AngularJS to write the tree code

Comment: @Sukesh, so, why you add `angularjs` tag? can you provide sample code that you already use? Why just not use angularjs for tree? :-)

Comment: @Sukesh, add code to your post instead of comment

Comment: @Grundy recently i added checkbox to the tree

Comment: @Sukesh, can you provide working plunkr with your code? now not clear what you mean when say _dynamic tree_.

Comment: @Grundy the solution what Nishi provided works. I also removed the function call like you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `ng-if="showHideComp(parentId)"` to child element. and inside showHideComp() function check the isSelected property of parentId and return true/false accordingly.

example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /></label><br/>
```

Show when checked:

```
<span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if">
   This is removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
</span>
```

Comment: using function in view not good for angular, because it call on every digest loop, why not just check _isSelected property of parentId_ without function?

Comment: @Nishi thanks for the suggestion,  will check and let you know

Comment: @Nishi your solution works great. But how do i modify it for the tree which is generated dynamically? I mean i can't use ng-model="checked" for all the list elements right?

Comment: generate dynamic id and check with that in ng-if

Comment: @Sukesh: you can try with ng-model also, because for all dynamic fields model will be separate.